# How to create bootable pendrive without ubuntu, windows, and other weird stuff?

Tags: usb-drive

Ok i have a linux box, i have syslinux installed there. I don't have any ubuntu box, and any windows. I know how to use cp, and dd, and what you want. Now I like to try ubuntu on netbook without cdrom.

My way to create bootable pendrive which works everytime is to use syslinux:

```
# mount -t iso9660 -o loop,ro /image.iso /mnt/cdrom/ 
# mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/pen/ 
# cp -r /mnt/cdrom/* /mnt/pen/

# mv /mnt/pen/isolinux/isolinux.cfg /mnt/pen/isolinux/syslinux.cfg 
# mv /mnt/pen/isolinux /mnt/pen/syslinux 
# sync

# umount /mnt/pen/ 
# syslinux /dev/sdb1
```

it is allways working, but not with ubuntu image :/

Answer (score 1):

You can `dd` the image directly to the drive.

```
dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: Beware of mistyping the command! Just one mistype of `if`, `of`, or `/dev/sdb`(Or whatever target disk you are using), and you can wipe out gigabytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sda
```

Make *VERY* sure `of` points to the correct device or you'll need a backup.

edit: I use this with Fedora, not sure if Ubuntu ISOs boot in the same way.